# New Rails application and bundle install execution error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm creating new applications which, as a last step, runs the `bundle install` command, which fails:

```
run  bundle install /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'   
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:330:in `bundle_command'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:346:in `run_bundle'  
from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'   
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'   
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'   
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'   
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'   
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'   
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rails:23:in `load'  
from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Why does it fail? I have bundler installed, but it gives me an error if I try to run it from the directory where I ran the `rails new` command:

```
khataev@~/Documents/development/rails$ bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

but inside the project directory it works fine. Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: As the error says: `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`. You have to provide a `Gemfile` or a proper `.bundle/` directory. Take a look into the [Getting Started](http://bundler.io/) section of the Bundler gem.

Comment: This error occurs hen I run bundle install command outside project directory and this is  right. I thought that this is the cause of my error (because I ran rails new outside newly creating project), but then I tried it (rails new) on another machine  and its bundle install completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question properly. So you are in a directory and you run for example "rails new test". This creates a new project folder called "test". You can run your bundle command only inside the "test" folder since that is the one containing the gemfile telling bundler what gems to install.

Comment: I know that I can run bundle install only inside project directory, but this question is about bundle install that is automatically triggered by rails new command after creating project structure. I have another learning VM with Ubuntu environment and there bundle install triggered by rails new completes successfully